# Disposing ActiveX resources owned by another thread

Tags: garbage-collection, activex, c#-2.0

I've got a problem problem with threading and disposing resources.

I've got a C# Windows Forms application which runs expensive operation in a thread. This thread instantiates an ActiveX control (AxControl). This control must be disposed as it uses a high amount of memory. So I implemented a Dispose() method and even a destructor.

After the thread ends the destructor is called. This is sadly called by the UI thread. So invoking activexControl.Dispose(); fails with the message "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW", as the object belongs to another thread.

How to do this correctly or is it just a bad design I use?

(I stripped the code down to the minimum including removing any safety concerns.)

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // do stuff here, e.g. open a form

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunStuff);

        // do more stuff
    }

    private void RunStuff()
    {
        DoStuff stuff = new DoStuff();
        stuff.PerformStuff();
    }
}

class DoStuff : IDisposable
{
    private AxControl activexControl;

    DoStuff()
    {
        activexControl = new AxControl();
        activexControl.CreateControl(); // force instance
    }

    ~DoStuff()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        activexControl.Dispose();
    }

    public void PerformStuff()
    {
        // invent perpetuum mobile here, takes time
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not clear what you mean by an ActiveX Control that implements a Dispose method.  The `IDisposable` pattern is intended for managed code.  To release a COM object, you would normally use `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` - perhaps you're doing that inside your `AxControl` class, whose implementation you don't show.

A couple of things wrong with the above code.

You should be disposing the IDisposable `DoStuff` instance:

```
private void RunStuff() 
{ 
    using (DoStuff stuff = new DoStuff())
    {
        stuff.PerformStuff(); 
    }
}
```

You should not be accessing managed resources in a finalizer - in your case the finalizer calls Dispose which then references the managed axControl instance.  This instance may have already been collected by the time your finalizer runs.

Since you are not using unmanaged resources directly in the DoStuff class, you probably don't need a finalizer, but if you do have one, follow the standard IDisposable pattern on MSDN, and don't attempt to dispose any managed objects.

**UPDATE**

Comment:

> The AxControl is the .NET Interop Wrapper DLL which is generated by Visual Studio.

In this case, what is the Dispose() method?  I don't see why you would implement such a method in an ActiveX control, which has deterministic finalization - normally you'd do your cleanup when the last COM reference is released.

Your `DoStuff.Dispose` method might want to release the COM object, e.g.

```
public void Dispose()  
{  
    activexControl.Dispose();  
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(activexControl);
}
```

Comment: The AxControl is the .NET Interop Wrapper DLL which is generated by Visual Studio. And there each ActiveX control is derived from the .NET control. (Surely to be able to place it onto a Windows Form).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you have the worker thread dispose of it explicitly?

You could possible change the

```
DoStuff stuff = new DoStuff();
stuff.PerformStuff();
```

To a

```
using(DoStuff stuff = new DoStuff())
{
     stuff.PerformStuff();
}
```

So you don't even have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with an active x control provided by a third party, so changing the disposal routine inside ActiveX is not possible.

I believe you are correct that the "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW" issue is a threading issue, not a dispose implementation issue.  COM just doesn't get along well with managed threads and managed memory.

Try something like this:

```
// Check to see if we need to use Invoke before wasting time with it
if (activexControl.InvokeRequired)
{
    // invoke Dispose on the control's native thread to avoid the COM exception
    activexControl.Invoke(() => activexControl.Dispose());
}
else
{
    // run dispose on this thread
    activexControl.Dispose();
}
```

The invoke is all that's needed to avoid the COM error, the if statement helps performance in cases where invoke is not required.

Do beware that the thread that created the active x control needs to still be alive, or you'll get different problems.  In your stripped down code main exits right after you spawn the new thread and it won't likely be alive when you need it later.  I run into this in unit testing all the time, and have to insert blocking calls that wait on the conclusion of other threads before exiting my top level function.